# How to put the result of executing a query into ViewData and pass to a view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm still a newbie in ASP.net MVC and having a problem displaying data when querying.

Here is the controller where I ran the query:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var Status = from s in _db.ReservationsStatus where s.defaultStatus == true select  s.Id;

    ViewData["Status"] = Status;
    return View();
}
```

I then read from ViewData in my view. However, the output is:

> SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id] FROM [dbo].[ReservationStatus] AS
>   [Extent1] WHERE 1 = [Extent1].[defaultStatus];

The output that I want is the ID itself (the *result* of executing the query).

Comment: what is the code you use in your view to display the data?

Comment: i used a variable `var x = ViewData["Status"]` then @x

Comment: I imagine you need to force evaluation of the query (perhaps `Status.First()`?)

Comment: Seriously it only took that!? I just added that and it worked!, I really lack on knowledge when it comes to asp.net mvc, Thanks Man!

Comment: That's actually not an MVC thing - more of a Linq/EF thing.

Comment: @MikeCole Then I am clearly a newbie but I'll try to strive through it and learn much more in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to execute the query.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var Status = (from s in _db.ReservationsStatus where s.defaultStatus == true select  s.Id).First();

    ViewData["Status"] = Status;
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ queries get executed in two modes - Deferred and immediate. In the case you mentioned it is deferred execution and hence the query gets assigned to the var until it gets executed. This will happen when you start traversing the result. You can make the query execute immidiatly by calling something like First or count that will force the query to execute and return a value.

Comment: I also used the count method for another reason and the query worked, I just lack knowledge when it comes to Linq and its methods. I  didn't know that using First() executes the query.